# Substitute when hold is on

Tags: replacement, hold

I have an expression for $div$ with Lame coefficients. I want to look at the $div$ in different coordinate systems. So I want to substitute the Lame coefficients not letting Mathematica to actually differentiate, thats why I am using hold. So I need a valid combination of hold and substution to get what I need. Here is my code

`divA = Hold[(1/(H1*H2*H3))*(D[Ax*H2*H3, x] + D[Ay*H3*H1, y] + 
     D[Az*H1*H2, z])]`

> Hold[(D[Ax*H2*H3, x] + D[Ay*H3*H1, y] + D[Az*H1*H2, z])/(H1*H2*H3)]

```
divA /. {H1, H2, H3} -> {1, 1, 1}
```

> Hold[(D[Ax*H2*H3, x] + D[Ay*H3*H1, y] + D[Az*H1*H2, z])/(H1*H2*H3)]

It is just dont substitute. Could u please help me get what I want?

Comment: Is is not replacing because there is no `{H1, H2, H3}` to replace... Try `divA /. Thread[{H1, H2, H3} -> {1, 1, 1}]`, it has nothing to do with `Hold`.

Comment: @Kuba it helped but not really, cause I got the next expression `Hold[(D[Ax*1*1, x] + D[Ay*1*1, y] + D[Az*1*1, z])/(1*1*1)]` It didn't do multiplication. I want multiplication to be done but not differentiation.

Comment: There are topics about injecting into held expression but the shortest way is to use `Inactivate` on `D`.

Comment: @Kuba ty, very much. That is exactly what I wanted. It helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, like this:

```
A = {H2*H3*Ax[x, y, z], H1*H3*Ay[x, y, z], H1*H2*Az[x, y, z]};
```

Then

```
    expr = 1/(H1*H2*H3)*Inactive[Div][A, {x, y, z}]


(*    Inactive[Div][{H2 H3 Ax[x, y, z], H1 H3 Ay[x, y, z], 
  H1 H2 Az[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]/(H1 H2 H3)   *)
```

And you may substitute:

```
expr1=expr /. Thread[{H1, H2, H3} -> {1, 1, 1}]

(* Inactive[Div][{Ax[x, y, z], Ay[x, y, z], Az[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]  *)
```

and then activate, if necessary:

expr1 // Activate

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @Kuba has already lit the light on `Inactivate[]` for me.